# Changing firewall settings after installation of CentOS via kickstart

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, system-installation, kickstart

I was trying to install CentOS 6.3 via Windows Deployment Server. And to automate the installation process I used kickstart file in which i provided various details required during installation.Then i wanted that machine to serve as mysql server that can be only accessed via ssh or mysql process,so i wanted to give the firewall rules via iptables. I have verified that these are correct and tested on existing machine.So I gave these these rules in %post section of the kickstart file ....but i encounted the following error **“can’t initialize iptables ‘filter’: Table does not exist”** .I have also taken care of the chroot environment but still the problem persisted.

Answer (score 4):

You want to provide the following lines in the kickstart file:

```
firewall --enable --ssh --port=mysql:tcp
```

The `%post` section only does things during the installation process.  You should let the install finish and reboot the machine and that `firewall` line should set the firewall rules for the box to allow only ssh and mysql (port 3306).